# Java 8 stream min is not returning expected value

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, min, flatmap

I am looking to get minimum value from a list of maps in java. I am using combination of flatmap,stream and min to do so and not getting expected results. Here is the code
    public class TestMin {

```
public  static class TestHolder{
    public  static Map<String,Integer> getValues(){
        Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("a",1);
        map.put("b",3);
        map.put("c",2);

        return map;

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Map<String, Integer>> l = new ArrayList<>();
    l.add(TestHolder.getValues());
    l.add(TestHolder.getValues());
    l.add(TestHolder.getValues());

    // Getting min
    int min = l.stream().map((m)->m.values()).flatMap((v)->v.stream()).min(Integer::min).get();
    System.out.println(min);
    }

}
```

Output is: 2

Of course, the output that I am expecting is 1. Trying some debugging suggests that it is providing an output a value corresponding to "c". i.e if map looks like

```
[a->2 , b->3, c->1]
```

Then the output I am getting is 1. 
The question is why it is not sorting by values and rather sorting by keys and providing me the unexpected output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Stream::min` expects something that adheres to the `Comparator` contract.  But `Integer::min` doesn't do that, it just returns the minimum of its two inputs.  You should be using `Integer::compare` instead.

Comment: Thanks, Oliver@ for the reply. As expected, you are right. A follow up question how can we catch such errors/bugs at compile time?

Comment: @maneet You can't, but you can write tests.

Comment: @maneet - This is a logic bug; it's not clear how one would be able to catch that at compile time (given that `Comparator::compareTo` returns an `int`).

Comment: Flown@ You  are right. Actually, that is how I caught this. Thanks Oliver@ for the reply :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `mapToInt()` function to convert `Stream<Integer>` to `IntStream` and then just call `min()` on it:

```
int min = l.stream()
        .map(Map::values)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
        .min().orElse(defaultMinValue);
```